# Maximum sum of product of two arrays

Tags: proof

Any math proof for maximum sum of product of two array achieved by maximum times maximum

```
A = {5, 2, 1, 3};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

`5*4 + 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1` is maximum sum.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe greedy algorithm?

```
Sort[{5, 2, 1, 3}].Sort[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> 34

Answer (score 4):

$x_1 \geq  x_2 \geq x_3$ and $a_1 \geq  a_2 \geq a_3$
we can deduce that
$$ x_1 a_1+x_2 a_2+x_3 a_3 \geq x_1 a_{j_1}+x_2 a_{j_2}+x_3 a_{j_3}$$
where $a_{j_1},a_{j_2},a_{j_3}$ is a permutation of $a_1,a_2,a_3$

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, a3}, 
    x1 >= x2 >= x3 && 
     a1 >= a2 >= a3, {x1, x2, x3}.{a1, a2, a3} >= {x1, x2, x3}.#], 
   Reals] & /@ Permutations[{a1, a2, a3}]
```

> `{True, True, True, True, True, True}`

Since $x_{i_1} a_{j_1}+x_{i_2}a_{j_2}+x_{i_3}a_{j_3}=x_1a_{k_1}+x_2 a_{k_2}+x_3a_{k_3}$, so we have deal with all the situations.

We can also use another way to list all the cases.

```
Outer[Resolve[
   ForAll[{x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, a3}, 
    x1 >= x2 >= x3 && 
     a1 >= a2 >= a3, {x1, x2, x3}.{a1, a2, a3} >= #1.#2], Reals] &, 
 Permutations[{a1, a2, a3}], Permutations[{x1, x2, x3}], 1]
```

> `{{True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True,  True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True,  True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True,  True, True, True, True, True}}`

**Appendix**

Here we prove it by hand.

**Lemma**

If $x_1\geq x_2$ ,$ a_1\geq a_2$,then $x_1a_1+x_2a_2\geq x_1a_2+x_2a_1$

**Proof**:
To prove this,just expand
$$(x_1-x_2)(a_1-a_2)\geq 0$$

Now we can use the above `Lemma` to arbitrary two terms of $$x_1a_{i_1}+x_2a_{i_2}+x_3a_{i_3}$$
Adjust the order for several steps to get the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You can also let Maximize test all Permutations of A and B.

```
A = {5, 2, 1, 3}; B = {1, 2, 3, 4};
xa = Array[x, 4]; ya = Array[y, 4];

possibx = Or @@ (And @@ Thread[xa == #] & /@ Permutations[A]);
possiby = Or @@ (And @@ Thread[ya == #] & /@ Permutations[B]);

max = Maximize[{xa.ya, possibx && possiby}, Join[xa, ya]]

(*   {34, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 2, x[3] -> 3, x[4] -> 5, 
           y[1] -> 1, y[2] -> 2, y[3] -> 3, y[4] -> 4}}   
 *)
```

In my version 8.0 the direct search for vectors xa,ya didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Wolfram Function Repository for [`ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaximizeOverPermutations)

```
A = {5, 2, 1, 3};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4};
{orderings, max} = ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"][
   A.B[[#]] &, Length@B];

result = B[[First[orderings]]]
A.result

(* {4, 2, 1, 3} *)
(* 34 *)
```